# Как изменять view элементы из класса унаследованного AsyncTask'ом

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Также попрошу проанализировать код и сказать что в нём можно было бы улучшить. Спасибо.

```
class SenderThread extends  AsyncTask<String, Void , String> {

private Socket socket;
InputStream sin;
OutputStream sout;
DataInputStream in;
DataOutputStream out;
Button get_string_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_string_button);//Горит красным.
Button get_screen_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.get_screen_button);
Button quit_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quit_button);
CloseSocket closeSocket = new CloseSocket();

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    .setEnabled(false);
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String line = null;
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
        strBuilder.append(params[i]);
    }
    String command = strBuilder.toString();
    try{
        if(socket == null){
            socket = new Socket(ip, 6666);
            sin = socket.getInputStream();
            sout = socket.getOutputStream();
            in = new DataInputStream(sin);
            out = new DataOutputStream(sout);
        }
        if(socket.isConnected()) {
            out.writeUTF(command);
            out.flush();
            line = in.readUTF();

            if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("getScreen") ){

            }
           closeSocket.close(in,out,socket);//закрывает потоки и сокет
            return line.toString();
        }else{
            throw new Exception("Socket not alive!");
        }
}catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.toString();

    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читаем [документацию](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

Для работы с UI у `AsyncTask` есть 3 метода:

1. `onPreExecute()` - вызывается до `doInBackground()`.
2. `onPostExecute()` - вызывается, когда завершится `doInBackground()`.
3. `onProgressUpdate()` - срабатывает, когда вы в `doInBackground()` вызываете `publishProgress()`.

Если в `AsyncTask` вы осуществляете какую-то долгую операцию и хотите периодически обновлять состояние UI, используйте переопределённый `onProgressUpdate()` с вызовом `publishProgress()`. Иначе же переопределите `onPostExecute()`, и обращайтесь из него к UI, как завершите все операции.

К примеру, вы хотите после завершения операции в `AsyncTask` отправить строку в UI.

1. Определяем интерфейс:

   ```
   public interface OperationResult {
      void onGetString(String str);
   }
   ```
2. Реализуете в вашей `Activity`:

   ```
   public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OperationResult  {
      public void onGetString(String str) {
          // обрабатываете результата выполнения вашего `AsyncTask`           
      }
   }
   ```
3. Немного меняете `AsyncTask` (добавляете конструктор, вызываете метод интерфейса).

   ```
   public  class SenderThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void , String> {
       private OperationResult  mCallBack;

       public SenderThread(OperationResult callBack) {
           mCallBack = callBack;
       }

       protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           mCallBack.onGetString(result);
       }

   }
   ```

Теперь когда создаёте ваш `AsyncTask` передавайте в конструктор ссылку на реализацию интерфейса. Если вы создаёте `SenderThread` прям в `Activity`, где реализуете интерфейс `OperationResult`, то передавайте в конструктор `this`.

Comment: Я не понимаю каким образом я могу onPreExecute() заставить поменять текст(например) view, так как он не наследник и не может найти id этого самого view.

Comment: Наследник AppCompatActivity я имею ввиду.

Comment: @Евгений в конструктор вашего `SenderThread`  прокидывайте нужные ссылки, а потом обращайтесь к ним.

Comment: Покажите как примерно это должно выглядеть, потому что до меня не доходит.

Comment: @Евгений обновил ответ.